# Proper way to store environment variables for cron jobs

Tags: cron, ksh, rhel7

We have a few ksh scripts, running as user cron jobs on RHEL7. user is set with /sbin/nologin.
What is the proper way to export environment variables so it is available to the ksh script running from cron?
/etc/environment
/etc/profile
.profile
.bashrc
another option?

I understand some only run on interactive session and some are bash specific, just not sure how it translates to ksh script running via cron.

Comment: Are you sure you are running ksh on RHEL7? When you have `bash` and change your tag, you have more viewers.

Comment: It depends on the script you want to run. Can you add more details about that script? I would put the variables inside the script, in `/usr/local/myprog/settings` or in the crontab command line.

Comment: Either put the variable in the script, or source a config file.